# FFMPEG: How to make the overlay loop till the end of the main video

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have this command line:

```
ffmpeg -i   Wildlife.wmv -vf   "movie=overlay.mp4, scale=250: -1 [inner]; [in][inner] overlay =10: 10 [out]" completed.mp4
```

Which placed the overlay.mp4 at the top left corner, it works just fine.

The overlay length is shorter than the main video, because of this reason the overlay will stop playing while the main video is playing.

I need the  overlay.mp4 to keep looping till the end of the video.

```
ffmpeg version N-59653-g9dd104f6e2-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 \
    -stream_loop -1 -i overlay.mp4 \
    -filter_complex \
    "[1:v]scale=250:-1[tmp];[0][tmp]overlay=shortest=1:x=10:y=10" \
    output.mp4
```

Explanation:

- First input is main video
- Second input is short overlay video that will be looped indefinitely with -stream_loop -1
- In filter_complex the second input video part [1:v] is first scaled and then assigned to [tmp]
- The main video [0] (video & audio) is overlayed with [tmp] at position x=10, y=10; shortest=1 assures that the output video will terminate at main video duration (because the overlay now runs indefinitely)

If you want to include audio from a 3rd input, do this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
    -stream_loop -1 -i overlay.mp4 \
    -i sound.mp3 \
    -filter_complex \
    "[1:v]scale=250:-1[tmp];[0:v][tmp]overlay=shortest=1:x=10:y=10 [vid]" \
    -shortest \
    -map [vid] \
    -map 2:a \
    output.mp4
```

Make sure the sound is longer than the input video, otherwise '-shortest' will end encoding at sound duration. Sound input can also be wav, flac, mp4, mkv, etc.

Comment: You'd better to update your previous answer instead of give another one.